Pyinstaller includes only dist-info
I am running pyinstaller and have multiple dependencies. Two of them are pandasgui and qtstylish. But for both dependencies it only includes the dist-info, not the package itself. When I try to execute my tool.exe I get the following error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI308162\\qtstylish\\compiled/dark.qss'

PyInstaller command:
pyinstaller --onedir --windowed --collect-submodules pandasgui --name tool -p . tool/main.py

requirements.txt
...
pandasgui==0.2.14 ; python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "3.11" \
--hash=sha256:22eac39cb44815091565862ecd7af6ac46fa383a7269755ad7c105585a1b988a
qtstylish==0.1.5 ; python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "3.11" \
--hash=sha256:3402562d8b92d0de3706a8478323a998bfe92f29572bdf07ef205895b1a1a29a
...

As you can see in the command I tried to solve the issue, by --collect-submodules pandasgui. If you need more informations just leave a command.

To solve your current error you can use the --collect-all flag with qtstylish as it's argument in order to collect all of the the additional files that come with the qtstylish package that aren't source modules.
For example you could do something like
pyinstaller -w --collect-all qtstylish --name tool -p . tool/main.py
